# Any alternatives to "e" in event handlers in React?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have a following React code snippet,

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const app = (
  <div className="App">
    <input
      type="button"
      value="Click me"
      onClick={e => alert(e.target.value)}
    />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, rootElement);
```

Here I have used `e` to grab an event object. Are there any other alternatives that I can use in event handler functions instead of `e` to perform the same operations?

Comment: You can use any name, not just `e`, if that's what you're asking

Comment: That is kinda alias for event object. You can name it as you want to.

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla Sorry I didn't mean naming, I meant to know another way to perform the same thing.

Comment: Kindle approve the answer you found helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Use `refs`

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const app = () => {
 const input = useRef()

 return (
  <div className="App">
    <input
      ref={input}
      type="button"
      value="Click me"
      onClick={() => alert(input.current.value)}
    />
  </div>
 )
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(app, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "e" in your example is the beginning of arrow function. It is something that you declares as you wish, then you are using it inside function.

You can change first "e" to any variable name you wish, then use it inside your function.

For further reading I recommend you [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) article abouy arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

React [supports](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes) all standard HTML attributes and events.

As `input` is [standard HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), its events handled by the event object.

You can implement a wrapper (like every UI library) and use any alternative you wish.

```
// The wrapper handles the event object internally
<Input onChange={(value) => setMyValue(value)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

That is just an alias for the **event** object. It is not required to denote it with **e** only but it depicts that it is an event.

Now as per your question which i saw in the post title and in the comment. You can use it differently as per your component design.

#### Functional:

```
const funComponent = (props)=>{
    const clickHandler = e=>{ 
       // use it here
    }

    return (<div className="App">
    <input
      type="button"
      value="Click me"
      onClick={clickHandler} // <----bind it here
    />
  </div>);

};
```

#### class:

```
class ClassComponent extends React.Component{
    const clickHandler = e=>{ 
       // use it here
    }

    render(){
        return(<div className="App">
                   <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Click me"
                      onClick={this.clickHandler} // <----bind it here
                />
      </div>);
    }

}
```